# jquery td click event

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fire a click event via jquery on td cells on a table.  I have it implemented for rows in a different table without any problems.  For reference, the table is a montly calendar and clicking on a square will pull up data for that day.

I could not get the event to fire so I stripped the code down to the basics and put it on its own page to ensure that nothing is interfering.  The table class in css is table.calendar and here's the code:

```
 $('table.calendar').delegate('td','click',function () {
        alert('Success');
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if (href) {
            window.location = href;
        }
    });
```

I've also tried it as .calendar without success.  I've confirmed that the class is correct on the table and there are no other classes.  I'm using `jquery 1.6`.

Any idea why the event is not firing?

Comment: Are you sure the table is added before you try to bind the event? Do you have your code wrapped in `$(document).ready(function...` or `$(function...`?? Anything to keep it waiting for the dom to load?

Comment: @AndreasAL [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) 'Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, **now or in the future**, based on a specific set of root elements.'

Comment: @Jashwant ya?? ... But I'm aksing if the table (root element) is added after the event is bound.

Comment: Yes, I got that later, I am the one who +1'ed your answer. There was no sense in deleting that, as that was a nice piece of info, so I let it there :)

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping your code in a ready callback:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('table.calendar').delegate('td','click',function () {
            alert('Success');
            var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
            if (href) {
                window.location = href;
            }
        });
});
```

If this dosn't work there is a big posibility that your `table.calender` is added async. Then try:

```
$(document).deligate('table.calendar td', 'click', function() {
    alert("Success!");
});
```

OR

```
$("table.calendar td").live('click', function() {
    alert("Success!");
});
```

If this dosn't work you dont have any table with class `calender` containing any `td`.

Comment: None of those work.  I also modified the class on the table to give it a pink background so that I was 100% certain it was hitting the table correctly.  I think that I don't 100% understand how the td click even works?

Comment: @JonLeach if you post an example and some HTML i can maybe help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the raw code.  Note that I'm using VS2010 so some of the code is coming from there.

```
<form method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" id="form1">
```

//

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    jQuery(function ($) {

        $('table.calendar').delegate('td', 'click', function () {

            alert('Success');

            var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

            if (href) {

                window.location = href;

            }

        });

    });
```

```
<div>

<table id="tblCalendar" class="calendar" rules="all" border="1" style="width:70%;float:right;border-width:2px;border-color:Gray">

<tr style="border-width:2px;border-style:solid;">

    <th><a id="LinkBack" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;LinkBack&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="font-size:Large;"><<</a></th><th align="center" colspan="1"><span id="CalendarTitle" style="font-size:Large;"></span></th><th align="center"><a id="LinkForward" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;LinkForward&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="font-size:Large;">>></a></th>

</tr><tr>

    <td class="Regular">3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>

</tr>
```

```
</div>

</form>
```